# Document not found for class Pet with id(s) pets_you_liked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

routes.rb

```
  post 'pets/pets_you_liked' => 'pets#pets_you_liked'
```

pets.js.coffee

```
  $.ajax
    type: 'POST',
    data: {pet_id: pet_id},
    url: "/pets/pets_you_liked"
```

rake routes

```
rake routes | grep pets_you_like
pets_pets_you_liked POST    pets/pets_you_liked(.:format)    pets#pets_you_liked
```

pets_controller.rb

```
def pets_you_liked
 raise 'checking'
end
```

I am Getting a routing error, Not able to understand where could be the error

Comment: try post `'/pets/pets_you_liked' => 'pets#pets_you_liked'` or `match "/pets/pets_you_liked/"=>'pets#pets_you_liked' ,:action=>"post"` and check

Comment: both getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow,

```
post '/pets/pets_you_liked' => 'pets#pets_you_liked
```